# curl cookie jar negative val

Tags: cookies, curl

Hey if I run this code cookie's experiation value is negative but server passes positive value.

Has someone idea what am i doing wrong? Or is it bug in curl core?

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://pinterest.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:11.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/11.0'); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'c:\xampp\htdocs\jar.txt');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'c:\xampp\htdocs\jar.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  ,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  ,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
$header = curl_exec($ch);
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

was using curl with pinterest also and having this same problem, seems to be an issue with their cookie being set to expire after 2038

Answer (score 0):

Here is a work around for negative cookie values in the curl cookie jar file

```
$cookiedata = file_get_contents($cookiefilename);
$cookiedata = str_replace("\t-", "\t", $cookiedata);
file_put_contents($cookiefilename, $cookiedata);
```

You might have to turn off CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION